# how to implement counting hashmap in c?

Tags: c, string, hashmap

I have 6 const strings (5 letters each)

I get a stream of few words (out of these 6 words).

I want to count how many occurrences were out of each word.

How can I implement it in C ?

I have tried:

```
  char searchEngineNames[6][5] = { "waze_", "faceb", "fours", "googl",
        "fueli", "yello" };

    static void foo(const char* res_name, int success, void *context, char *last_modified) {
        if (success){
                for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
                {
                    char substringFiveChars[6];

                    strncpy(substringFiveChars, res_name, 5);

                            char substringFiveChars[6]; 

                            substringFiveChars[5] = 0;

                    if (strcmp(searchEngineNames[i],substringFiveChars) == 0)
                    {
                    ... 
                    }
    ..
                }
```

for example for this stream:

> "wooo_","wooo_","faceb","wooo_","google"

I will eventually get:

> 

```
"wooo_" 3 times

"faceb" 1 times 

"google" 1 times 

"fours" 0 times

"fuelil" 0 times

"yello" 0 times
```

Comment: If you know how to implement a simple hashmap (and it is easy), you simply take a string as key and an unsigned int as value. I'm not sure to understand what have you tried so far.

Comment: the problem I don't have string in C. only char*. Then I have to use 3d array?

Comment: Without knowing your programming skills, it's hard to know how to answer. Are you familiar with linked lists and how a hashmap works?

Comment: You need to get a hash from your string and use this hash to get the index in the array that is in your hashmap. I don't understand why the "3d array".

Comment: If you have 6 5-letter words then you can do that with a 2D array: `char [6][5]`. There's no need to use any pointers, so no `*`.

Comment: `char searchEngineNames[6][5][1]` Is this the thing that your intended?

Comment: When you say "I want to count how many occurrences were out of each word.", are you referring to the 5 const strings? Can you give an example of result, just to be sure?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I have thought that too. No hash and no nothing. It's all const. But how do I count? Can you please add code?

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. "wooo_","wooo_","faceb","wooo_","google" is your stream of words? or your five const strings? Because in your question you say you have 5 const strings and in the example I understand you have 6.

Comment: @Maxime of course this is the stream. If it were the five const words, there would be no duplications

Comment: Ok, so your **5** const strings are the **6** following strings: "wooo_", "faceb", "google", "fours", "fuelil", "yello". Please edit.

Comment: @Maxime. Sorry. Edited

Comment: You say "I have 6 const strings (5 letters each)", but "google" and "fuelil" are words of 6 letters. Plus, why are you using strncpy and strcmp instead of strncmp?

Answer (score 0):

I use 2 arrays instead of 1.

```
char searchEngineNames[6][5] = { "wooo_", "faceb", "fours", "google",
        "fuelil", "yello" };

int searchEngineCounts[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};



static void foo(const char* res_name,
        int success, void *context, char *last_modified) {
    if (success) {

        int i = 0;
        for (i; i < 6; i++) {
            char substringFiveChars[6];

            strncpy(substringFiveChars, res_name+7, 5);

            substringFiveChars[5] = 0;

            if (strcmp(searchEngineNames[i], substringFiveChars) == 0) {
                searchEngineCounts[i]++;

                if (searchEngineCounts[i] < 3) {

...
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That is not a hashmap. You are comparing the current word of your stream to **all** the searchEngineNames. You must use a hash function (see http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html for instance) and implement a hashmap (an array of linked lists where the list is selected according to the hash value).