# index out of bounds in c array

Tags: c, arrays, string, exception

I get an exception on the last line.

Im not sure why, as `res_name="engine_wooo_idle"`

meaning long enough.

```
static void searchEnginesIcons_download_callback(const char* res_name,
        int success, void *context, char *last_modified) {
    if (success) {

        int i = 0;
        for (i; i < 6; i++) {
            char substringFiveChars[6];

            strncpy(substringFiveChars, res_name+7, 5);
```

I have tried:

```
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < 6; i++) {
        char substringFiveChars[6];

        substringFiveChars[5] = '0';

        strncpy(substringFiveChars, res_name+7, 5);
```

but it throws exception as well

none of this worked as well:

```
substringFiveChars[5] = 0;

substringFiveChars[5] = '\0';
```

Comment: What is the `for` loop for? And please post the error message and which line it is referring to.

Comment: Index is not getting out of bounds if the value provided by you is correct. If you could provide some more code, then it can be further looked upon.

Comment: I think you left out the important part of the loop.

Comment: Please post a trace or something. I'm not so sure the exception is on the last line...

Comment: Instead of doing `substringFiveChars[5] = '0';` do: `substringFiveChars[5] = '\0';` Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Note that `strncpy()` will not terminate this "sub-string", since there are more than 5 characters before the `'\0'` in `res_name + 7`.

This could lead to all sorts of issues, depending on how you later use `substringFiveChars`. Since your code isn't complete, it's hard to tell for certain.

Note that this means that even though the variable is called `substringFiveChars`, it really doesn't *contain* a valid substring. If you were to e.g. call `strlen()` on it after the `strncpy()`, it would invoke undefined behavior.

You should be more clear about what the "exception" you're seeing really is, and also show more code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **explicitly include the '\0'** character after the string has been copied.

Without the '\0' character, many string api's would result in erroneous behaviour.

Comment: He knows that according to that previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522342/how-to-implement-counting-hashmap-in-c/